# Calculating the memory usage of RoBERTa?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm currently training Roberta for sentiment classification and having a fixed mini-batch size is killing my performance. To the extent that running the stuff I'm running will take 8-9 days to cover the training set once. Is there a general equation for calculating the memory usage of RoBERTa given n_inputs, input_length and input embedding size? If I have this I should be able to efficiently mini-batch on the fly (it has to be done during runtime due to other libraries that I'm using).

(If it helps in anyway I'm using PyTorch to do this)

Comment: Maybe you can try [link](https://github.com/jacobkimmel/pytorch_modelsize).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I think that tool only guesses the size of the model. I was looking for an equation for the memory usage when running different sized inputs / batch sizes through the model.

Comment: The readme mentions the following parameters: `se.param_bits # bits taken up by parameters`, `se.forward_backward_bits # bits stored for forward and backward` and `se.input_bits # bits for input`. That sounds like exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: sorry I missed that, ye that looks great I'll give it a test now

Comment: It's very close to what I'm looking for however it calculates `se.forward_backward_bits` by actually running the model which isn't ideal